# How to loop a string an array in string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

```
const names = 'const names = ["jhon", "anna", "kelvin"]'
```

how to get the names array so i can loop through it

for example names.forEach(name => console.log(name))

// expected results jhon, anna, kelvin

Comment: Why you take the const in the let? This approach is not right. You can take the array in let names.

Comment: because i take the code from the user input (in my real project)

Comment: Whatever you do, avoid the eval and use something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/73752586/1277159

Comment: _i take the code from the user input (in my real project)_. That gives me shivers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this one:

```js
let testCase1 = 'const names = ["jhon", "anna", "kelvin"]';
let testCase2 = 'var names = ["cane", "anna", "abel", 1, {}, []]';
let testCase3 = 'var names = ["cane" "anna", "abel", 1, {}, []]';


function getArrayLikeInsideText(text) {
    const regex = new RegExp(/\[.*\]/, 'g');
    const temp = text.match(regex);
    let arr;
    try {
        arr = JSON.parse(temp);
    } catch {
        return undefined;
    }
    const gotAnArray = Array.isArray(arr);
    return gotAnArray ? arr : undefined;
}

console.log(getArrayLikeInsideText(testCase1)); // ["jhon", "anna", "kelvin"]
console.log(getArrayLikeInsideText(testCase2)); // ["cane", "anna", "abel", 1, {}, []]
console.log(getArrayLikeInsideText(testCase3)); // undefined
```

Comment: that works perfectly for my use cases, but it's using the eval function can you refactor it to not using the eval function?

Comment: Ok, I rewrite it using JSON.parse instead of eval. Still work fine.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `match()` here to isolate the array, followed by a `split()` to obtain a list of names.

```js
var names = 'const names = ["jhon", "anna", "kelvin"]';
var vals = names.match(/\["(.*?)"\]/)[1]
                .split(/",\s*"/)
                .forEach(name => console.log(name));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
eval('const names = ["jhon", "anna", "kelvin"]');
for(let name : names)
console.log(name);
```

Comment: There are downsides of using `eval` which you need to highlight to the user and this a code only answer

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by using a `RegEx` with the help of [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const names = 'const names = ["jhon", "anna", "kelvin"]';

const a = names.match(/\[.*\]/g)[0];

JSON.parse(a).forEach(name => console.log(name));
```

`\[.*\]`  - Including open/close brackets along with the content.